# Why I can't load data from database in my javafx application?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, jdbc, scenebuilder

I was working on a project to build a note-taking app. I have a form where users can create categories of notes. Such as work, study and so on are examples of the categories of notes. Although users can create categories successfully. Their data can be stored in the database without any kind of issue. But the problem is I can't load those data in my application to display the user. A user should display all the categories he/she made in a tabular format but my application shows an empty table. Here is my code:

> ViewCategories.java

```
package com.example.noteapp;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class ViewCategories {
    @FXML
    private Stage primaryStage; // Declare the Stage reference

    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }


    @FXML
    private Menu createnote;

    @FXML
    private Menu viewnote;

    @FXML
    private Menu takenote;

    @FXML
    private MenuBar optionmenu;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Categories> categorytab;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Categories, String> categoryname;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Categories, Integer> catid;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Categories, Date> created_date;

    public void initialize() {
        catid.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        categoryname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("category_name"));
        created_date.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("created_date"));
        viewCategories();
    }

    @FXML
    public void viewCategories(){
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/noteapp";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "";


        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
            String sql = "Select * from category";
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            ObservableList<Categories> categories = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                int id = resultSet.getInt("catid");
                String category_name = resultSet.getString("categoryname");
                Date created_date = resultSet.getDate("created_date");
                Categories category = new Categories(id,category_name,created_date);
                categories.add(category);
            }

            categorytab.setItems(categories);

            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
//            showAlert("Successfully login", "Login as "+u);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Connection failed.");
        }
    }

}
```

I intend to display database data but my application shows an empty table. I am sure that my database isn't empty. If any other piece of code is needed, please let me know.

As I got some comments to share Categories class, here I am sharing that

> Categories.java

```
package com.example.noteapp;
 
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
 
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.io.IOException;
 
public class Categories {
    private int id;
    private String categoryName;
    private Date createdDate;
 
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
 
    public String getCategory_name() {
        return categoryName;
    }
 
    public Date getCreated_date() {
        return createdDate;
    }
 
    @FXML
    private Stage primaryStage; // Declare the Stage reference
 
    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }
 
    public Categories(){}
 
    public Categories(int id, String categoryName, Date createdDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
 
 
    @FXML
    private TextField categoryid;
 
    @FXML
    private Button createbtn;
 
    @FXML
    private Menu view;
 
    @FXML
    private MenuBar menubar;
 
    @FXML
    public void createCategory(){
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/noteapp";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "";
 
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
            String sql = "insert into category(category_name) values (?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            String cat = categoryid.getText();
            statement.setString(1, cat);
            statement.executeUpdate();
 
            showAlert("Created Successful", "201 created!");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Connection failed.");
        }
    }
 
    @FXML
    public void showCategories(){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("categorylist.fxml"));
            AnchorPane categoryLayout = loader.load();
            Scene loginScene = new Scene(categoryLayout);
 
            // Access the controller of the login.fxml file and pass the primaryStage reference
            ViewCategories categoriesController = loader.getController();
            categoriesController.setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
 
            primaryStage.setScene(loginScene);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 
    private void showAlert(String title, String message) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText(message);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
 
}
```

I am new to JavaFX, so please consider.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `categorytab.setItems(categories)` and make sure categories is not an empty list.

Comment: I assume you already tried hard-coding some `Category` objects and adding them to the table, instead of loading them from the database. What happened when you tried that?

Comment: Nothing to do with your question but the following looks strange. `@FXML
    private Stage primaryStage; // Declare the Stage reference

    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }`

Comment: show the Categories class

Comment: @Anon here is my Categories class. https://pastebin.com/wtRcz63s

Comment: Post the `Categories` (sic) class *in the question*. Don't use external links to code.

Comment: hmm `new PropertyValueFactory<>("category_name")` should be `new PropertyValueFactory<>("categoryName")` and the same for date but im not really sure  since you dont use the normal naming conventions of java like this getter for ex `getCategory_name` it should be `getCategoryName`